# Delete Row Using PHP Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, post

could someone help on below code? I have table data on that can allow user to click button to delete the row. I got error said " Undefined index: tenant_id " , Undefined variable: row.  Below are delete.php and pg-t-payment-view.php script :

```
            <?php  
            $db = pg_connect("host=10.0.32.204 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres"); 
            $id = $_POST['tenant_id'];

            $sql2 ="DELETE FROM payment_ref_tenancy WHERE tenant_name = '$id'";

            $result = pg_query($sql2);
            $cmdtuples = pg_affected_rows($result);
            echo $cmdtuples . " record affected.\n";
            if (!$result) {
                $errormessage = pg_last_error();
                echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
                exit();
            }
            pg_close();

            header('location:pg-t-payment-view.php');

            ?>
```

-------------pg-t-payment-view.php script

```
          <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
             <?php  
            $db = pg_connect("host=10.0.32.204 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres"); 
            $sql2 ="select tenant_id,to_char(last_update_time, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI') as last_update_time , tenant_name, tenant_cost_category, invoice_no,tenant_agreed_cost,
            to_char(submission_date, 'MM-dd-yyyy') as submission_date,to_char(cpr_submission_to_finance, 'MM-dd-yyyy') as cpr_submission_to_finance,io,cheque_no 
            FROM payment_ref_tenancy order by insert_datetime desc limit 10";

            $result = pg_query($db,$sql2);
            if (!$result) {
                $errormessage = pg_last_error();
                echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
                exit();
            }
            pg_close();

                echo "<table class='table table-hover table-striped'>";
                echo "<th align='center' >Date</th>";
                echo "<th align='center' >Payee</th>";
                echo "<th align='center' >Category</th>";
                echo "<th align='center' >Cost (RM)</th>";
                echo "<th align='center' >Invoice No</th>";
                echo "<th align='center' >Payment Submission Date</th>";
                echo "<th align='center'>CPR Submission to Finance</th>";
                echo "<th align='center'>IO</th>";
                echo "<th align='center'>Cheque No</th>";
                echo "<th align='center' div style ='color:#ff0000'>Action</th>"; 
                echo "<th align='center'></th>";
                echo "<th align='center'></th>";


                while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result))
                { $id = $row['tenant_id'];

                echo "<tr>";                                
                echo "<td>" . $row['last_update_time'] . "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>" . $row['tenant_name'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $row['tenant_cost_category'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $row['tenant_agreed_cost'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $row['invoice_no'] . "</td>";  
                echo "<td>" . $row['submission_date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cpr_submission_to_finance'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['io'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cheque_no'] . "</td>";

                echo  "<td><a href='pg-t-payment-edit.php'>Edit</a></td>";

                echo  "<td><a href='delete.php?id=$id'><input type='hidden' name='id' value=$id>Delete</a></td>";  
                echo "</tr>";} 
                echo "</table>";
```

?>

Comment: Did you get id here $id = $_POST['tenant_id'];?

Comment: I didn't get id. I just got message " 0 record affected "  from the url :  http://10.0.32.230/paytrack/delete.php?id=TC77192 when the button clicked

Comment: Try $result = pg_query($db, $sql2);

Comment: Similar problem. The error is "Undefined index: tenant_id in /var/www/html/paytrack/delete.php on line 5, referer: http://10.0.32.230/paytrack/pg-t-payment-view.php "  .    I corrected the code                                                                  $id = $_POST['tenant_id'];

            $sql2 ="DELETE FROM payment_ref_tenancy WHERE tenant_id = '$id'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move `pg_close();` in `pg-t-payment-view.php` somewhere after you have already worked with data fetched from database.
So basically after this loop executes: `while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result))`

Change name of argument you pass in your delete button to reflect column name or change in `delete.php` how you get said ID.

```
          <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
         <?php  
        $db = pg_connect("host=10.0.32.204 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres"); 
        $sql2 ="select tenant_id,to_char(last_update_time, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI') as last_update_time , tenant_name, tenant_cost_category, invoice_no,tenant_agreed_cost,
        to_char(submission_date, 'MM-dd-yyyy') as submission_date,to_char(cpr_submission_to_finance, 'MM-dd-yyyy') as cpr_submission_to_finance,io,cheque_no 
        FROM payment_ref_tenancy order by insert_datetime desc limit 10";

        $result = pg_query($db,$sql2);
        if (!$result) {
            $errormessage = pg_last_error();
            echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
            pg_close();
            exit();
        }

            echo "<table class='table table-hover table-striped'>";
            echo "<th align='center' >Date</th>";
            echo "<th align='center' >Payee</th>";
            echo "<th align='center' >Category</th>";
            echo "<th align='center' >Cost (RM)</th>";
            echo "<th align='center' >Invoice No</th>";
            echo "<th align='center' >Payment Submission Date</th>";
            echo "<th align='center'>CPR Submission to Finance</th>";
            echo "<th align='center'>IO</th>";
            echo "<th align='center'>Cheque No</th>";
            echo "<th align='center' div style ='color:#ff0000'>Action</th>"; 
            echo "<th align='center'></th>";
            echo "<th align='center'></th>";


            while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result))
            { $id = $row['tenant_id'];

            echo "<tr>";                                
            echo "<td>" . $row['last_update_time'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td>" . $row['tenant_name'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . $row['tenant_cost_category'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . $row['tenant_agreed_cost'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . $row['invoice_no'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . $row['submission_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cpr_submission_to_finance'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['io'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['cheque_no'] . "</td>";

            echo  "<td><a href='pg-t-payment-edit.php'>Edit</a></td>";

            echo  "<td><a href='delete.php?tenant_id=$id'><input type='hidden' name='id' value=$id>Delete</a></td>";  
            echo "</tr>";} 
            pg_close();
            echo "</table>";
?>
```

Change in your delete.php how you get and use ID. If your tenant_id is integer, you can omit quotes from `DELETE` query.

```
        <?php  
        $db = pg_connect("host=10.0.32.204 port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=postgres"); 
        $id = $_GET['tenant_id'];

        $sql2 ="DELETE FROM payment_ref_tenancy WHERE tenant_id = '$id'";

        $result = pg_query($sql2);
        $cmdtuples = pg_affected_rows($result);
        echo $cmdtuples . " record affected.\n";
        if (!$result) {
            $errormessage = pg_last_error();
            echo "Error with query: " . $errormessage;
            exit();
        }
        pg_close();

        header('location:pg-t-payment-view.php');

        ?>
```

Just so you know, this code can be SQL Injected, this is security issue if untrusted people will use it.

Comment: Already remove pg_close() . I am still got error said " Undefined index: tenant_id in /var/www/html/paytrack/delete.php on line 6, referer: http://10.0.32.230/paytrack/pg-t-payment-view.php " . I curious  the url is http://10.0.32.230/paytrack/delete.php?id=TC77191. I see it pickup the tenant_id , then it did not POST the value to delete.php. Don't you think that the script of echo  "<td><a href='delete.php?id=$id'><input type='hidden' name='id' value=$id>Delete</a></td>";   is correct ?

Comment: You are correct, delete.php will not use this value you are passing in anchor. So you either need to change delete.php and `$id = $_GET['id'];` or change your anchor. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Lukasz ! It worked , thank you. But I got curious the using of POST as compared to GET. The objective is same , in real the POST is more secure than GET. Right now, I start enable the pg_close() to follow the script code

Comment: There isn't much difference in security between POST and GET other than in POST you need to create custom form, while GET required a bit less time consuming method of just modifying URL. Both can be easily fabricated and provide no security.